# How to create a python 2.7 environment variable?

Tags: python-2.7, environment-variables

I have multiple versions of python installed so I wanted to create a command for each of them.  I created the variable "python27" as both a user and system variable with the path "C:\Python27" and also tried "C:\Python27\python.exe".  In both cases cmd says 'python27' is not recognized as an internal or external command.

My batch file is simply "python27 path_to_py_file".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a batch file for this. For example:

```
@C:\Python27\python.exe %*
```

Save this as `python27.bat` in a directory referenced by the `PATH` environment variable and you are good to go.

Comment: How come just plain old 'python' works as a variable in cmd without the need to make a bat file though?  What is different from the regular 'python' variable and my 'python27' variable that makes it not function the same?

Comment: @mediumwall the `python` command is not a variable. It's an executable in a directory referenced by the `PATH` environment variable. If you have a `python` variable, then it's not actually doing any work.

Comment: Ah!  Thanks for clearing that up!  I just appended the numbers 27, 34, etc to each of the exe's and now it's doing what I want.

Comment: And I also see why your solution works now.  Thanks!